# Canvas drawing through function with template strings

Tags: javascript, canvas

I would like to refactor several functions that are responsible for drawing different types of colored boxes (bonuses). I tried to do it this way:

```
function drawBonus(type) {
  properties = {
    type,
    x: randomTen(0, width - 10),
    y: randomTen(0, height - 10)
  };
  ctx.fillStyle = `${properties.type}Color`;
  ctx.strokeStyle = `${properties.type}BorderColor`;
  console.log(`${properties.type}Color`, `${properties.type}BorderColor`);
  console.log(slowBonusColor, slowBonusBorderColor);
  ctx.fillRect(properties.x, properties.y, 10, 10);

  console.log(properties.type);
}
```

And then I called a function in hopes that this would actually draw the specified square.

```
drawBonus(`slowBonus`);
```

I have constants defined and the very beginning of the file:

```
const slowBonusColor = "yellow";
const slowBonusBorderColor = "darkorange";
let properties;
```

While the console logs actually log what I was intending to get, thus: slowBonusColor, slowBonusBorderColor, then yellow, darkorange, the canvas drawing does not execute as supposed.

Is there any other way that I could pass the parameter in order to draw a bonus based on specific details? I would not like to have several functions that are responsible for drawing different kinds of squares.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By

```
ctx.fillStyle = `${properties.type}Color`;
```

you assign string "slowBonusColor" to fillstyle, not actual value of variable slowBonusColor.

If the function is in the same scope with variable slowBonusColor and others, you can try something like this:

```
ctx.fillStyle = this[`${properties.type}Color`];
```

or if those variables are in the global scope:

```
ctx.fillStyle = window[`${properties.type}Color`];
```

or if those variables are in a object:

```
ctx.fillStyle = objOfVars[`${properties.type}Color`];
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much! I went with the object version.